# Gulp-js pass only saved file on to task

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

I want to pass a saved file which does not need to be compiled or does not need to be saved to a new location to gulp-tap so I can run an external script on it.

Right now I watch a complete directory and on each save I upload the whole directory:

```
gulp.task('shopify_theme',function(){
gulp.src( './theme/**/*.liquid' )
    .pipe(tap(function(file){
          upload(file);
    }));
})
```

And this is the upload part (theme is an application that uploads assets to shopify)

```
var upload = function( file ){
var splitPath = file.path.split('theme/').pop();
run('theme upload ' + splitPath, { cwd: 'theme' }).exec();
};
```

Every time I save a liquid file in the /theme directory all files (theme/**/*.liquid) are uploaded. gulp-changed doesn't work as at the time the task runs the destination and the source are the same.

What's the best way to only upload the changed file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `gulp.watch` to watch for changes to individual files:

```
var upload = function(filePath){
  var splitPath = filePath.split('theme/').pop();
  run('theme upload ' + splitPath, { cwd: 'theme' }).exec();
};

gulp.watch('./theme/**/*.liquid', function(evnt) {
  upload(evnt.path);
});
```